# Use Composer for Deployment from windows to ubuntu

Tags: yii, composer-php

I am new in using composer PHP. We are having a ERP System. We are using yii framework for development. I am assigned in Deployment of the system so I need to study how to deploy it to the ubuntu 16.04 LTS using the composer. My question is is there a way deploy the the system using the composer in offline mode?

All answers will be appreciated

Comment: Composer just pulls dependencies into the project/vendor/ directory, you can do 'composer install' where you have connection, then just copy your full project including vendor dir to a deployment server.

Comment: Copy the project to a flash drive...

Comment: Okay. thanks for the comments. What is your suggestion in deploying the yii project to ubuntu? What deployment process you know? thanks. Any suggestion will be appreciated.